# How efficient is Python's 'in' or 'not in' operators, for large lists?

Tags: python, iteration, complexity-theory

I have a list of over 100000 values and I am iterating over these values and checking if each one is contained in another list of random values (of the same size).

I am doing this by using `if item[x] in randomList`.
How efficient is this? Does python do some sort of hashing for each container or is it internally doing a straight up search of the other container to find the element I am looking for?

Also, if it does this search linearly, then does it create a dictionary of the randomList and do the lookup with that?

Comment: There isn't an `is in` - I presume you mean `in` ?

Comment: I've always wanted to write `is in`. :/

Comment: those are _[operators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.contains)_, not _methods_

Comment: @SylvainLeroux where is it implied they are methods?

Comment: I assume you mean `if item[x] in randomlist`, not `...in randomlist[x]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`in` is implemented by the `__contains__` magic method of the object it applies to, so the efficiency is dependent upon that. For instance, `set`, `dict` and `frozenset` will be hash based lookups, while `list` will require a linear search. However, `xrange` (or `range` in Python 3.x) has a `__contains__` method that doesn't require a linear search, but instead can use the start/stop/step information to determine a truthy value. (eg: `7 in xrange(4, 1000000)` isn't done linearly).

Custom classes are free to implement `__contains__` however they see fit but ideally should provide some information about how it does so in documentation if "not obvious".

Comment: Aha good point, I was wondering about xrange also. So is that the same for range??

Comment: @Smac89: range under Python 2 creates a list.

Comment: @Smac89 no - `range` actually generates a list in Python 2 - so it'd have to do a linear search. But in Python 3, then `range` is the same as `xrange` in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to pre-convert your list to a set, where hashing can be used for O(1) lookup.

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

(Normally, you have to search every element in a 'classical' list to tell if something is in it (unless your data structure also keeps a set of all elements, but that would add a huge amount of time and space complexity, and the programmer can implement it themselves).)

Comment: So does that mean it actually does the search linearly?

Comment: Yes, `list`s are searched linearly. That's why you want to change it to a `set`.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. I usually used 'in' and 'not in' with both lists and dicts/sets thinking they are the same time complexity, but now I know

Comment: If you want to change it to a set or not depends entirely on how large the list is and how many times you are going to do lookups. So there is no "you will want to". Except "if it's slow you'll want to do performance testing".

Comment: @LennartRegebro: actually he will want to, since he mentioned he is performing this operation multiple times.

Comment: "multiple times" is not enough. Making a set() also takes time.

Answer (score 1):

ninjagecko already answered the specific case of lists (and tuples FWIW), the general answer is : "it depends on the 'container' implementation" (I quote 'container' cause it can as well be a generator). For builtin types, you want sets or dicts for a fast lookup. Else you'd better check the doc or implementation for your container.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using a set if the two lists are sorted, as follows:

```
def gen(P1, P2):
    i, j = 0, 0
    I, J = len(P1), len(P2)
    while i != I and j != J:
        if P1[i] == P2[j]:
            yield P1[i]
            i, j = i + 1, j + 1
        else:
            if P1[i] < P2[j]:
                i += 1
            else:
                j += 1
```

This returns the intersection of P1 and P2:

```
>>> P1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 90]
>>> P2 = [2, 3, 5, 30, 48]
>>> list(gen(P1, P2))
[2, 3, 5]
```

The algorithm is described [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/processing-boolean-queries-1.html).