# to display the numbers ranging b/w a particular range?

Tags: python

consider the example:

```
      l = [11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 30, 40]
```

now i need to display the numbers ranging b/w 12 to 16 so the output must be

```
        [12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
```

I did write a sample code but it displays the entire input:

```
       l = [11,12,13,14,14,15,16,12,17,18,19,19,20,30,40]
       for i in range(len(l)):
            if ( l[i]==12):
                 print l
```

the output was:

```
        [11,12,13,14,14,15,16,12,17,18,19,19,20,30,40]
```

if anyone could suggest a code in python to do this it will be helpful.........

Comment: Why are you printing the whole list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 30, 40]

print [ f for f in l if f in xrange(12, 17) ]
```

If you are worried about the `in xrange(12, 17)` incurring extra memory usage, see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220296/how-efficient-is-pythons-in-or-not-in-methods)

Output:

```
[12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print [x for x in l if 12 <= x <= 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [11,12,13,14,14,15,16,12,17,18,19,19,20,30,40]
for i in range(len(l)):
    if ( l[i]==12):
        print l
```

This code says, "when you find an item in the list that is equal to 12, print the whole list." This is why you are getting the whole list printed: it's what you told Python to do. You probably want to print `l[i]` instead of `l` as that is the number you are looking at.

You can now adjust the `if` statement to choose only the numbers between 12 and 16:

```
if 12 <= l[i] <= 16:
```

Now you've got the numbers, you can work on the formatting. The easiest way to get the output you want is to build up a list and print it at the end:

```
l = [11,12,13,14,14,15,16,12,17,18,19,19,20,30,40]
o = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if 12 <= l[i] <= 16:
        o.append(l[i])
print o
```

There are other improvements you can make after that. For example, you can iterate over the numbers in the list directly, rather than the list indices, which you do not otherwise need:

```
for n in l:
    if 12 <= n <= 16:
        o.append(n)
print o
```

And now you can write it as a list comprehension, a Python language feature designed for making the common pattern of building lists much simpler:

```
print [n for n in l if 12 <= n <= 16]
```