# Pandas: Dealing with missing column in input dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python code which performs mathematical calculations on multiple columns of the dataframe. This input comes from various sources so there is a possibility that sometimes one column is missing from the same.

This column is missing because its insignificant but i need to have a null column atleast for the code to run without errors.

I can add a null column using if loop but there are around 120 columns and i do not want to slow down the code. Is there any other way where the code can check each column is present in the original dataframe and then if any column is not present it adds a null column and then starts with execution of the actual code?

Comment: provide some sample data, expected output and your efforts

Comment: i think the question is pretty straight forward. Identify missing column and add it to the dataframe. I have also mentioned that i am using if loop. Not sure why sample data is required in this case. No reason to downvote either.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the column name is the same for every dataframe you could do something like this without having to loop over the column names

```
if col_name not in df.columns:
    df[col_name] = '' # or whatever value you want to set it to
```

If speed is a super concern, which I can't tell, you could always convert the the columns to a `set` with `set(df.columns)` and reduce the search to O(1) time because it will be a hashed search. You can read more in detail on the efficiency of the `in` operator at this link [How efficient is Python's 'in' or 'not in' operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220296/how-efficient-is-pythons-in-or-not-in-operators)

Comment: yes, i am using this approach, but wont it slow down the code?

Comment: If you had posted that you were already doing this then I wouldn't have wasted my time posting this answer. Please be considerate of other peoples time when asking questions on Stack Overflow and consult the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not sure what is the misunderstanding. I have already mentioned that i can add a null column with if loop in my question.

Comment: `if` statements are not loops